# Error after reinstall, "dconf-CRITICAL Permission denied. dconf will not work properly."

Tags: permissions, dconf, default-browser

I'm on a reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04, and noticed that the default web browser won't start. I tried through the terminal, but get an error message about denied permissions (below).

Ideas of how to fix it?

```
(webbrowser-app:2905): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/run/user/1000/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

(webbrowser-app:2905): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/run/user/1000/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

(webbrowser-app:2905): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/run/user/1000/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
libGL error: Version 4 or later of flush extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: i915
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed: No such file or directory
unity::action::ActionManager::ActionManager(QObject*):
    Could not determine application identifier. HUD will not work properly.
    Provide your application identifier in $APP_ID environment variable.
UCUriHandler: Empty "APP_ID" environment variable, ignoring.
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/webbrowser/ContentPickerDialog.qml:22:1: module "Ubuntu.Content" is not installed
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/webbrowser/ContentDownloadDialog.qml:22:1: module "Ubuntu.Content" is not installed
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/ContentHandler.qml:20:1: module "Ubuntu.Content" is not installed
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/webbrowser/DownloadHandler.qml:20:1: module "Ubuntu.DownloadManager" is not installed
Input device added: "Power Button" "/dev/input/event2" QFlags(0x1)
Input device added: "Video Bus" "/dev/input/event4" QFlags(0x1)
Input device added: "Lid Switch" "/dev/input/event0" QFlags(0x20)
Input device added: "Power Button" "/dev/input/event1" QFlags(0x1)
Input device added: "Lenovo EasyCamera" "/dev/input/event7" QFlags(0x1)
Input device added: "HDA Intel PCH Headphone" "/dev/input/event9" QFlags(0x20)
Input device added: "HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3" "/dev/input/event10" QFlags(0x20)
Input device added: "HDA Intel PCH Mic" "/dev/input/event8" QFlags(0x20)
Input device added: "Ideapad extra buttons" "/dev/input/event6" QFlags(0x1)
Input device added: "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" "/dev/input/event3" QFlags(0x1|0x10)
Input device added: "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "/dev/input/event5" QFlags(0x4|0x8)

(webbrowser-app:2905): IBUS-WARNING **: Unable to connect to ibus: Could not connect: Permission denied
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
intel_do_flush_locked failed: Invalid argument
```

Comment: How did you fix this one?